# How to find the last match of a string in a bunch of files

Tags: command-line, unix, grep, pipe, tail

I have a bunch of files, I'd like to find the last match of a string in each of them.

`grep text *.file` gives me all the matches not the last ones.

`ls *.file | xargs grep text | tail -n 1`  gives me the last line of the last file that matches.

So what I think I want is a way to say:

```
ls *.file | (xargs grep text | tail -n 1)
```

But I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tail -n 1` in a `for` loop. For example:

```
for name in *.file; do
    grep -H text "$name" | tail -n 1
done
```

(The `-H` option will make `grep` always print the file name, even if only one file was given.)

Comment: +1 for the `-H` option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a oneliner over a `tac` commad, that output file from end till begin:

```
find . -name *.log -exec sh -c "tac '{}' | grep -Hm1 text " \;
```